# FFmpeg - avcodec_receive_frame doesn't receive all frames and lose frames before receving frames

Tags: ffmpeg

The `vcodec_receive_frame` function didn't receive the rest of the frames. I tested that there were totally 132 frames of the video and it only received 125 frames **losing 7 frames at the END of the video**. How can I get the lost frames back?

But something weird happened. As you can see the output from my `MyDecode::receiveFrame()` function. The code inside the block `if (ret != 0){}` executed first, but the lost frames are at the end of the video. So how could they come out first? What caused this happen?

**MyDecode.cpp**

```
AVFrame* MyDecode::receiveFrame()
{
    mux.lock();
    if (!codecCtx) {
        mux.unlock();
        return 0;
    }
    AVFrame* frame = av_frame_alloc();
    int ret = avcodec_receive_frame(codecCtx, frame);
    mux.unlock();
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        static int lost_frames = 1;
        std::cout << "Lost frames: " << lost_frames << std::endl;
        lost_frames += 1;
        av_frame_free(&frame);
        return nullptr;
    }
    std::cout << "Received frames: " << received_frame_num << std::endl;
    received_frame_num += 1;
    return frame;
}

bool MyDecode::sendPacket(AVPacket* packet)
{
    if (!packet || !packet->data || packet->size == 0)
        return false;
    mux.lock();
    if (!codecCtx) {
        mux.unlock();
        return false;
    }
    int ret = avcodec_send_packet(codecCtx, packet);
    mux.unlock();
    av_packet_free(&packet);
    if (ret != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Console output**

```
Total frames: 132
Lost frames: 1
Lost frames: 2
Lost frames: 3
Lost frames: 4
Lost frames: 5
Lost frames: 6
Lost frames: 7
Received frames: 1
Received frames: 2
Received frames: 3
................
Received frames: 125
```

**UPDATE:**

**MyDemux.cpp**

```
AVPacket* MyDemux::readFrame()
{
    mux.lock();
    if (!formatCtx) {
        std::cout << "formaetCtx is null" << std::endl;
        mux.unlock();
        return nullptr;
    }
    AVPacket* packet = av_packet_alloc();
    if (!packet) {
        std::cout << "packet is null" << std::endl;
        mux.unlock();
        return nullptr;
    }

    int ret = av_read_frame(formatCtx, packet);
    if (ret != 0) {
        while (true) {
            av_read_frame(formatCtx, nullptr);
        }
        mux.unlock();
        av_packet_free(&packet);
        av_packet_unref(packet);
        return nullptr;
    }
    media_type = packet->stream_index;
    mux.unlock();
    return packet;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
while (true) {
            AVPacket* pkt = demux.readFrame();
            if (demux.get_media_type() == 0) {
                AVFrame* frame = video_decode.receiveFrame();
                videoWidget->paintFrame(frame);
            }
            else if (demux.get_media_type() == 1) {
            }
            if (!pkt) {
                std::cout << "to break" << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to send NULL pkts to the decoder to drain all pending frames.

From avcodec.h

> End of stream situations. These require "flushing" (aka draining)
>   the codec, as the codec might buffer multiple frames or packets
>   internally for performance or out of necessity (consider B-frames).
>   This is handled as follows:
>     - Instead of valid input, send NULL to the avcodec_send_packet() (decoding)
>       or avcodec_send_frame() (encoding) functions. This will enter draining
>       mode.
>     - Call avcodec_receive_frame() (decoding) or avcodec_receive_packet()
>       (encoding) in a loop until AVERROR_EOF is returned. The functions will
>       not return AVERROR(EAGAIN), unless you forgot to enter draining mode.
>     - Before decoding can be resumed again, the codec has to be reset with
>       avcodec_flush_buffers().

Comment: I've tried. But I have no ide how to do this sepecifically like where should I place `avcodec_send_frame(codecCtx, NULL)`.

Comment: Once you receive EOF from the input, skip this check: `if (!packet || !packet->data || packet->size == 0)` and send NULL till you receive no frames.

Comment: `int ret = avcodec_receive_frame(codecCtx, frame); if (ret == AVERROR_EOF) {}` like this? not working